# Selenium: get the url of a button when clicking without being redirected to the page

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, request

Scraping the page https://www.milanuncios.com/viviendas-en-eixample-esquerra-barcelona-barcelona/?demanda=n&fromSearch=1&orden=date, i try to get the next page without being redirected. The problem is that the button does not have the next page url in the html so i cannot get it with beautiful soup or selenium directly, it only appears when clicking:

```
div_list = driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR,value='[class = "ma-NavigationPagination"]')
nav_list = div_list.find_elements(by=By.TAG_NAME, value = "button")
nav_list[-1].click()
```

The code above finds and click the button, but redirects to it.

What i need to do is **get the url of that click without being redirected** to the page using selenium or beautifulsoup.

Notes:

- The webpage is script created, so a simple request is  unable to
  reach the button part by itself.
- I am using firefox executable `driver =    webdriver.Firefox(options=options,    executable_path=r'geckodriver.exe')`

Comment: I think is impossible what i am asking, click returns void and only executes the element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the URL, It has a parameter "pagina".

https://www.milanuncios.com/viviendas-en-eixample-esquerra-barcelona-barcelona/?demanda=n&fromSearch=1&orden=date&pagina=2

You could iterate over an int range, so clicking the next page button isn't necessary.

```
for page_b in range(1, 100):
    url = f"https://www.milanuncios.com/viviendas-en-eixample-esquerra-barcelona-barcelona/?demanda=n&fromSearch=1&orden=date&pagina={page_n}"
     #### Scrape process ####
```

Comment: It's a nice idea but gives a diferent result. this button generates a token in the `url` that gives a different result in the page that the one you posted. https://www.milanuncios.com/viviendas-en-eixample-esquerra-barcelona-barcelona/?demanda=n&fromSearch=1&orden=date&nextToken=eyJkaXIiOiJmIiwiaWQiOiIzNzA4MTI5NzkiLCJkYXRlIjoxNjUyMzA4ODA2MDAwLCJwcmljZSI6MCwiY3VycmVudFBhZ2UiOjF9&pagina=2

Comment: The token is base64 url encoded. If you decode it its simple json:
{"dir":"f","id":"449856209","date":1652317382000,"price":730000,"currentPage":1}

Could you generate this json and encode it to append it in the manualy crafted URL?

Comment: I don't think so, if you check the token for the third page it has changed, it's not the same token i do not see the pattern

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Maybe it's not mandatory to have that token

Comment: My problem is that the button click causes problems in scrapping, but getting the link does not. Getting the url without the token changes the items in the webpage and may not be able to perform a complete scrap